# Writer monad operator definition issue

Tags: haskell

I want to define `>>=` operator for a Write monad.
I tried something like that but it doesen't work (Does not compile). May I get some help? Thanks

```
newtype Writer a = Writer { runWriter :: (a, [String]) }

instance Monad Writer where
    return = Writer

    Writer m >>= f = Writer $ \r ->
        (runWriter (f m) r)
```

I get this:

```
Couldn't match type ‘a’ with ‘(a, [String])’
```

I get this error at return line, but also `>>=` is not defined well, I'm trying to get it right.

Comment: "It doesn't work" isn't terribly descriptive.

Comment: Please view the later edit

Comment: `return (x :: a) = Writer (x :: (a, [String]))`?  Shouldn't that be `return x = Writer (x, [])` or something similar?

Comment: Knowing _where_ you get this error would be useful. (I presume it's complaining about `return`, since the type signatures won't match up.)

Comment: You'll next have a problem with `f m`, since `m :: (a, [String])` and `f :: a -> Writer b`.

Comment: Yes, at return line. Please see later edit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First: The type signature for `return` should be `x -> Writer x`. However, the type signature of `Writer` is currently `(x, [String]) -> Writer x`, which is wrong.

Second: `Writer m >>= f = Writer $ \r -> ...` But the argument to `Writer` isn't declared to have a function type. So that doesn't look like it's going to work. Also, you're calling `f :: x -> Writer y` with an argument of type `(x, [String])`, which can't work.

In short, the whole thing as it stands just isn't right. So that's why it won't compile; not sure how many hints you're after on how to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

`Writer` constructor expects a tuple of `a` and what is already written. `return` writes nothing so

```
return a = Writer (a, [])
```